# is this a valid java date string "2022-08-22T10:18:00.000 10:00"? date format can not parse this string

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-format, date-format, timezone-offset

I can parse the ff. date string with the format below.

`"2022-08-20T00:03:00.000+10:00" -> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`

`"2022-08-20T00:03:00.000 +10:00" -> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS XXX"`

`"2022-08-20T00:03:00.000 +10:00" -> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS X"`

however, I cannot parse this "2022-08-22T10:18:00.000 10:00". time zone part does not have a +/- sign. I this a valid date string? Got this from a rest api response.

Comment: Valid according to what specification?  There are a myriad different possible formats for date / type values.

Comment: The ISO 8601 datetime formats require that the timezone offset starts with a `+` or `-`.   See https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.  However, unless you know what format that REST API claims to implement, it is not possible to say whether the above string is "valid" or not.

Comment: Also, you don't mention which Java date formatting class you are using.  That could be significant ... in terms of figuring out how to parse the string (if you decide it is "valid").

Comment: No, it’s not valid. Could it be that it has mistakenly gone through [URL decoding](https://ascii.cl/url-decoding.htm)? That would alter a `+` sign to a space. Without an explicit sign we would at the very least need another way to know whether -10 or +10 hours was intended. And parsing would not work out of the box.

Comment: The first format, `2022-08-20T00:03:00.000+10:00` without any space, does not require any format pattern string at all. `OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-08-20T00:03:00.000+10:00")` does it. This is because the string falls within the subset of ISO 8601 that the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse()` accepts.

Comment: time zones with hours require a *sign*, either using the old **¹** `SimpleDateFormat` (see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone)) or the actual `DateTimeFormatter`/`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` (see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))) || **¹** usage not recommended

Comment: If by *date format* and/or the date-format tag you referred to the `DateFormat` and/or `SimpleDateFormat` classes, I strongly recommend you avoid using those classes. They are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, maybe even `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: hi all, if we are going to include the time zone in the pattern "2022-08-22T10:18:00.000 10:00" it's not a valid date string. however, we can parse the string if we ignore the timezone part. pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS".  @OleV.V. yeah this could be a mistake on the api side.

Comment: Possibly, just guessing, the error was that the string should have been URL encoded on the sending end (into `2022-08-22T10%3A18%3A00.000%2B10%3A00`), which it wasn’t. Then when you decode it, you get `2022-08-22T10:18:00.000 10:00` (with space instead of `+`). If this is the explanation, see if you can’t get the error fixed at the root, on the sending end.

Comment: It's a third party api btw. I don't have access to their code base. i just informed them anyway bout the issue.